# Single page application utilizando apenas html, css e javascript puro sem frameworks

Tags: javascript, single-page-application

Olá
estava tentando algo apenas para fins de estudo.
Queria saber existe uma forma de fazer isso:

fazer uma single page application, sem utilizar nenhum framework externo, apenas html, js e css.

o que eu esta tentando era:

- Criar uma tag html fake `<include src='componentes/menu.html'>`
- Utilizar a tag para injetar outros arquivos, como se fossem componentes, meio que imitando o react ou angular.
- Ao carregar o html principal, um js inspeciona a DOM e coleta os `<includes>`
- Carregar e injetar os arquivos referenciados na propriedade `src`.

Eu fiz usando o xmlHttpRequest para carregar os arquivos, algos assim:

```
Array.from(includes)
    .forEach(function (include_) {
        let url = include_.attributes.item(0).value;
        if (url.indexOf("./") !== 0) {
            url = './' + url;
        }
 
        const xmlhttp  = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onload=(resq) => {
            const html = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlhttp.responseText, "text/html");
            const h = html.documentElement
            h.id = 'patos'
            
            include_.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', h);
            const a = document.createElement('div');
            const patos =  document.getElementById('patos')
 
            Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('script')).forEach(element =>{
                patos.appendChild(element)
            })
            
 
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET",url ,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
 
    });
```

As tags `<link>` com os css são carregadas normalmente, o problema é as tags `<script>`, elas não são carregadas.
É possível fazer algo assim? Existe uma forma mais adequada?

Comment: bem vindo Henrique, traduza o titulo da sua pergunta pf

Comment: sim é possível, mas pelo que entendi quer fazer isso sem frameworks tbm, com puro javascript? é possível, pq no final qualquer framework javascript é feito usando o basico do javascript, mas vai ter de escrever a lógica de rotas na mão, e para quem não conhece muito isso pode ser complexo, melhor usar um framework que suporte isso, como Angular

Comment: Então, meu objetivo e não utilizar esses frameworks como angular ou react. Mas queria entender como isso é feito, e antes de olhar código, eu tento imaginar formas e implementar, acho que fica mais fácil de assimilar o conteúdo posteriormente, seja olhando a doc ou o código.
Mas no momento eu estou nesse impasse.

Comment: já que pretende refazer o que esses frameworks já fazem, sugiro olhara para o código fonte deles, isso vai ajudar a entender o que precisa fazer